# ZedGraph SetScaleToDefault Function?

Tags: zedgraph

I am having trouble when refreshing ZedGraphControl. Basically, what happens is that the scale gets messed up when I refresh the graph with completely new values. Sometimes it becomes too small, sometimes too big. Here is what I do when refreshing:

```
zgcControlAmp.AxisChange();
zgcControlAmp.Refresh();
```

When the scale gets messed up, I need to RightClick->SetScaleToDefault to fix the view, but sometimes it still messes up. When working with a clean graph (first run) however, all is good.

Any tips how to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
zgcControlAmp.AxisChange();
zgcControlAmp.Invalidate();
```

after refreshing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
zgcControlAmp.RestoreScale(zgcControlAmp.GraphPane);
```

Where`zgcControlAmp.GraphPane` can be replaced with whatever GraphPane you are working with.
(This is the same function that occurs when you RightClick->SetScaleToDefault)